# extract information of a excel sheet with multiple sections

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file with a sheet that has several sections, say something like:

List of books

Author: John Doe

Title: a big book

ISBN: 123456

Year: 2023

Author: Jane Doe

Title: another big book

ISBN: 78901

Year: 2024

List of papers:

Authors: Doe, Jane; Doe, John; High, Ami.

Journal: NotNature

DOI: 1234567

below i attach an image of the file, but is in spanish

[image]

and so on. All sections (shown here in gray) have headers (within each sheet, same name everytime), but its length is variable for each file , so how can i automate, using python, to extract information of each cell within each section. I already have code for a specified range:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def iterating_over_values(path, sheet_name, cell_range):
    workbook = load_workbook(filename=path)
    if sheet_name not in workbook.sheetnames:
        print(f"'{sheet_name}' not found. Quitting.")
        return

    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    for column in sheet[cell_range]:
        for cell in column:
            if isinstance(cell, openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
                # Skip this cell
                continue
    
            print(f"{cell.value}".split("\n"))
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    iterating_over_values("file.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1",
                          cell_range="A10:A20")
```

but ideally the code would detect each section, rather than having to put it manually

Comment: It's hard to tell because of the shrouding you've done, which seems unnecessary, but it looks like there is a blank line at the end of each section.  That should make it easy to detect a section change.

Comment: I did the shrouding because it's information from an institution, i'm not sure I can share it. Definitively each section is in a new line, after a blank one.